# Lambda expression to SQL query without external DLL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, iqueryable

I'd like to convert a lambda expression into a SQL query. To do this, I have done:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}

var user = new List<User>();
IQueryable<User> query = user.Where(x => x.Age >= 33).AsQueryable();
```

The 'query' variable is *{System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[Domain.User]}*.

However I want the `IQueryable<User> query = user.Where(x => x.Age >= 33).AsQueryable();` code becomes `'select FirstName, LastName, Address, Age from User where Age >= 33'`

How can I do this?

Important note:

- I am not using EF because the data base is OLE DB.

Comment: @Pac0 I don't think that link helps any...

Comment: "I am not using EF because the data base is OLE DB." - OK; so what *are* you using? Are you saying that there *isn't* currently a query generator, and you want to get SQL for a particular query?

Comment: side note: to be *even remotely* usable, you'd actually need that code to be `user.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Age >= 33)` -

Comment: You need to query against your LINQ provider, not a `List<>`. What LINQ provider are you using to access OLEDB?

Answer (score 0):

When you compose queries, internally a new query is formed by creating a new (probably larger) `Expression`-tree (`query.Expression`), all of which sits on top of the *provider* (`query.Provider`).

If you don't currently *have* a provider (other than LINQ-to-Objects), then in theory you should still be able to take the *expression tree* from a query (via `query.Expression`), but you still have *all the work ahead of you* in terms of generating SQL from that. That's pretty much the entire purpose of the provider. It doesn't help that there is no single "OLE DB" syntax for anything - you still need to issue commands in the particular language variant that the actual endpoint expects.

So; you can *get the lambda* via something like:

```
var query = list.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Age >= 35);
var lambda = query.Expression;
```

but to do this yourself you'd have to tease the expression tree apart carefully, discard the root list object, just taking the inner lambda to the `Expression.Call` (for the "Where"), then write your own SQL generator that understands some basic expression trees *and* understands the SQL variant that you want to emit.

Frankly, this is going to be *a lot* of work, and it probably isn't a great use of your time. If all you need to support is basic filters, it would probably be quicker to write a shunting-yard implementation of a basic filter DSL.